# Beautifulsoup returns only h1 from the last HTML source code:

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have this algorithm below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


data = [{"operationName": "SearchQuery", "variables": {"query": "Python", "after": None, "first": 2},
         "query": "query SearchQuery($query: String!, $first: Int!, $after: ID) {\n  questionSearch(query: $query, first: $first, after: $after) {\n    count\n    edges {\n      node {\n        id\n        databaseId\n        author {\n          id\n          databaseId\n          isDeleted\n          nick\n          avatar {\n            thumbnailUrl\n            __typename\n          }\n          rank {\n            name\n            __typename\n          }\n          __typename\n        }\n        content\n        answers {\n          nodes {\n            thanksCount\n            ratesCount\n            rating\n            __typename\n          }\n          hasVerified\n          __typename\n        }\n        __typename\n      }\n      highlight {\n        contentFragments\n        __typename\n      }\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n}\n"}]
r = requests.post("https://brainly.com.br/graphql/pt", json=data).json()

p=[]    
for item in r[0]['data']['questionSearch']['edges']:
    rst=(f"https://brainly.com.br/tarefa/{item['node']['databaseId']}")
    p.append(rst)

for ele in p: 
    r = requests.get(ele).text 


soup = BeautifulSoup(r,'html.parser')

for n in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'brn-content-image'}):    
   print(n.find('h1').text)
```

And I Need To Filter These 2 `HTML`:

```
<div class="brn-content-image">
<h1 class="sg-text sg-text--large sg-text--regular">
O que é for em python?​
</h1>
```

And:

```
<div class="brn-content-image">
<h1 class="sg-text sg-text--large sg-text--regular">
Linguagem ( Python )<br /><br />a) Quem foi(ram) o(s) criador(es) do python? <br /><br />b) Cite como se declara uma variáveis:<br /><br />c) O que é uma variável?<br /><br />d) O que é uma função?<br /><br />e) para que serve às { } no python?​​
</h1>
</div>
```

Expected Exit:

1 h1 - Linguagem ( Python )

a) Quem foi(ram) o(s) criador(es) do python?

b) Cite como se declara uma variáveis:

c) O que é uma variável?

d) O que é uma função?

e) para que serve às { } no python?​​

2 h1 -O que é for em python?​

I Have 2 `HTML` Page In The Same Variable; 
The problem that I can only filter the 2 h1 ie >> O que é for em python?​

And I need to be printing both! What I'm Doing Wrong:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`soup` variable you have used outside for loop that is why you are getting 2nd html value only.That should be inside for loop.Try Now.

```
for ele in p:
    r = requests.get(ele).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r,'html.parser')

    for n in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'brn-content-image'}):
        print(n.find('h1').text)
```